# Difference between 'function pointer' and 'pointer to a function' in C language

Tags: c

What is the main difference between 'function pointer' and 'pointer to a function' in C language?

Explain with an example.

Comment: don't give me orders !! what make you think there's a difference ?

Comment: There is no difference. Check [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Time to play with [C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org/)

Comment: Sounds like homework to me

Answer (score 2):

A variable of type `int` often referred as `int` variable. A pointer to `int` is referred as `int` pointer. In similar way *pointer to a function* is referred as *function pointer*.